# Neo4j transaction log corruption

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j 4.2.1 Community edition on Ubuntu Server 20.04

A database I administer is failing to start with this error:

`"Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading transaction logs, recovery not possible. To force the database to start anyway, you can specify 'unsupported.dbms.tx_log.fail_on_corrupted_log_files=false'. This will try to recover as much as possible and then truncate the corrupt part of the transaction log. Doing this means your database integrity might be compromised, please consider restoring from a consistent backup instead."`

If I roll back to the server instance from yesterday the database runs fine, but it goes through a recovery step as follows:

```html
2022-07-10 12:21:23.825+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.d.Database] [neo4j/2443e357] Recovery required from position LogPosition{logVersion=0, byteOffset=191545629}
2022-07-10 12:21:27.676+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.r.Recovery] [neo4j/2443e357]   10% completed
2022-07-10 12:21:28.578+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.r.Recovery] [neo4j/2443e357]   20% completed
2022-07-10 12:21:29.715+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.r.Recovery] [neo4j/2443e357]   30% completed
2022-07-10 12:21:31.078+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.r.Recovery] [neo4j/2443e357]   40% completed
2022-07-10 12:21:32.140+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.r.Recovery] [neo4j/2443e357]   50% completed
2022-07-10 12:21:32.709+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.a.i.IndexingService] [neo4j/2443e357] IndexingService.init: indexes not specifically mentioned above are ONLINE
2022-07-10 12:21:37.360+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.r.Recovery] [neo4j/2443e357]   60% completed
2022-07-10 12:21:39.550+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.r.Recovery] [neo4j/2443e357]   70% completed
2022-07-10 12:21:40.971+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.r.Recovery] [neo4j/2443e357]   80% completed
2022-07-10 12:21:42.104+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.r.Recovery] [neo4j/2443e357]   90% completed
2022-07-10 12:21:43.128+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.r.Recovery] [neo4j/2443e357]   100% completed
2022-07-10 12:21:43.151+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.d.Database] [neo4j/2443e357] Recovery completed. 195143 transactions, first:98943, last:294085 recovered, time spent: 18s 577ms
```

It clearly isn't 100% ok though because if I try to run a backup with `sudo neo4j-admin dump --database=neo4j --to=~/` I get the following error:

```html
Active logical log detected, this might be a source of inconsistencies.
Please recover database before running the dump.
To perform recovery please start database and perform clean shutdown.
```

Starting and shutting it down makes no difference.

All the backups within our retention period have this problem.

We execute a script daily which performs a lot deletes and inserts on the database.  When I run this on the working instance and re-start the database, the database fails to restart and I get the error I first listed again.

So it seems that the corruption in the transaction logs has been lingering for some time and that running this batch of deletes and inserts "pushes it over the edge", making it fail.  Incidentally, this script has been running daily for 2 years now without any issues, so I'm sure it's not the script itself causing problems.

I tried setting `dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=keep_none` before running the script and that made no difference, although the failed start error becomes:

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.exceptions.UnderlyingStorageException: No check point found in any log file from version 1 to 2`

I also tried deleting the transaction log files as a desperate measure.  That just broke things as expected.

I'm running community edition and my backups are EC2 server instances, so I don't believe that I need the transaction logging feature.

How can I fix or remove the transaction logs please?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on my production database, only
neo4j-admin copy helped me

Answer (score 0):

Old transaction logs cannot be safely archived or removed. So you might use `dbms.directories.transaction.logs.root` to change the root location where Neo4j will store transaction logs.

Or, if the problem might be about memory, you can control which file size the logical log will auto-rotate by `dbms.tx_log.rotation.size`.

Comment: Thank you Roy.  So if I change the `dbms.directories.transaction.logs.root` location will it start with new transaction logs at that location.  i.e. just abandon the ones that are corrupted?

Comment: Yes. The most recent non-empty transaction log for any particular configuration will be retained.

Comment: I changed dbms.directories.transaction.logs.root to `/home/ubuntu/neo4jTLs` and ran `chown neo4j:neo4j neo4jTLs` to give permissions. Stopped and started neo4j server and get error `Transaction logs are missing and recovery is not possible. To force the database to start anyway, you can specify 'dbms.recovery.fail_on_missing_files=false'. This will create new transaction log and will update database metadata accordingly.`.  I update `dbms.recovery.fail_on_missing_files=false` and get the same error. No transaction logs created. Reduced `dbms.tx_log.rotation.size`.

Comment: It created new transaction log, but then failed as it had originally.  Also tried setting `dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=keep_none` to rotate out the corrupted transaction log. Can I create a new database and copy the data files into that or anything similar?

Comment: Which version are you using? As mentioned here https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12119. Try these steps:

Shut down the database.
Open Neo4j terminal.
Type bin/neo4j console.
Once the startup is done, press Ctrl+C to shut down the database.
Finally, run neo4j-admin dump respectively.

Comment: From a different perspective, It appears something bad has happened to the system and transaction logs are missing. Making this change in the config file will force new transaction logs to be created and the warning that recovering any data that were in those logs won't be possible but at least you'll be able to get your system running again.  Try `dbms.recovery.fail_on_missing_files=false`

Comment: Thank you.  I tried the console approach and that gives this error "Active logical log detected, this might be a source of inconsistencies. Please recover database before running the dump. To perform recovery please start database and perform clean shutdown.".  I'd actually tried that previously with the same result.


I'm on neo4j 4.2.1 and I've also tried the dbms.recovery.fail_on_missing_files=false option.  When I do this the database runs but I get the recovery steps 0-100% that I mention at the start of my question every time and it still fails when further inserts are done. Thanks.

Comment: It's annoying I know. I am trying to help with all the possible solutions, but this can happen if the last backup was incremental. To fix it you have to first start the database up on 4.1, wait for it to complete recovery, and shut it down again. Then try starting it on 4.2.1 again.

Comment: Thanks Roy, I greatly appreciate your helping me with this. :)  Are you saying that I should downgrade the actual version of Neo4j to Neo4j 4.1, start the DB with dbms.recovery.fail_on_missing_files=false and then upgrade again to 4.2.1 and start it?

Comment: Exactly, Try it with the lowest version, then to the newest one. If it failed with 4.1 try it with the lowest.